# How to use CONTAINS in dbpedia SPARQL query with german umlaut?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to query dbpedia in german for abstracts that contain certain words. However, I got a problem with the german umlaute. Is it possible to use the code below (that works if there is no umlaut) also with an umlaut?

```
SELECT Distinct *
Where
{          
     ?resource dbo:abstract ?abstract.      
     Filter langMatches(lang(?abstract),"DE").        
     ?abstract bif:contains "Düsseldorf".    
}
```

Or do I have to use REGEX for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead of "Düsseldorf" just use "Dusseldorf". Replace "ü" with "u", "ä" with "a", "ö" with "o" and "ß" with "ss". If you want differenciate between umlauts and the replaced characters, you'd have to use regex and unicode hex.

Comment: Thanks, that was easier than i thought